# Python Debugged EXE Output to PYC <class 'ValueError'>; bad marshal data (unknown type code) Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pyc

I am trying to completely de-compile an EXE file I made using *Pyinstaller*. I am using a tool called *pyinstxtractor* AKA *PyInstallerExtractor* to debug the EXE. I am trying to convert the output of the debugger to a PYC file, but when I prepend the magic numbers from a current PYC file within the output of the debugger to the output I am converting to a PYC file I think the file gets corrupt, like I am doing it wrong. The reason I think this is because I am using *uncompyle6* to convert the PYC file back to Python code I get this error:

```
# path . must point to a Python source that can be compiled, or Python bytecode (.pyc, .pyo)

File '-o' doesn't exist. Skipped
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\deanm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xdis-5.0.7-py3.8.egg\xdis\load.py", line 293, in load_module_from_file_object
    co = marshal.loads(bytecode)
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\deanm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xdis-5.0.7-py3.8.egg\xdis\load.py", line 293, in load_module_from_file_object
    co = marshal.loads(bytecode)
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\deanm\anaconda3\Scripts\uncompyle6-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('uncompyle6==3.7.4', 'console_scripts', 'uncompyle6')())
  File "C:\Users\deanm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uncompyle6-3.7.4-py3.8.egg\uncompyle6\bin\uncompile.py", line 193, in main_bin
  File "C:\Users\deanm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uncompyle6-3.7.4-py3.8.egg\uncompyle6\main.py", line 316, in main
  File "C:\Users\deanm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uncompyle6-3.7.4-py3.8.egg\uncompyle6\main.py", line 183, in decompile_file
  File "C:\Users\deanm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xdis-5.0.7-py3.8.egg\xdis\load.py", line 163, in load_module
    return load_module_from_file_object(
  File "C:\Users\deanm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xdis-5.0.7-py3.8.egg\xdis\load.py", line 306, in load_module_from_file_object
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Ill-formed bytecode file test_decompile.pyc
<class 'ValueError'>; bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

Here are screenshots of me attempting to convert the debugger output to a PYC file (in order from copy to paste):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Python 3.7 and above has a 16 byte header. But you're copying 12 bytes, must be a version mismatch somewhere.

Comment: Oh Okay, thank you!